# SDL2 converting SDL1.2 code in C, how to scroll a Window, previously SDL_BlitSurface

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm converting SDL 1.2 code to SDL 2 in C and I have encountered code that  scrolls a Window (SDL 1.2 SDL_Surface named nanoglk_surface) of text to allow empty space for new lines at the bottom:

```
  // Copy (scroll down).
  SDL_Rect r1 = { win->area.x, win->area.y + d,
                  win->area.w, win->area.h - d };
  SDL_Rect r2 = { win->area.x, win->area.y, win->area.w, win->area.h - d };
  SDL_BlitSurface(nanoglk_surface, &r1, nanoglk_surface, &r2);

  // Clear new, free area.
  SDL_Rect r = { win->area.x, win->area.y + win->area.h - d,
                 win->area.w, d };
  SDL_FillRect(nanoglk_surface, &r,
               SDL_MapRGB(nanoglk_surface->format,
                          win->bg[win->cur_styl].r,
                          win->bg[win->cur_styl].g,
                          win->bg[win->cur_styl].b));
```

This is part of an open source C app, here: https://github.com/BroadcastGames/nanoglk/blob/master/nanoglk/wintextbuffer.c - the whole app compiles and runs fine on Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10. But I'm attempting to update it to SDL 2.0 conventions.

The app has only a single window with associated renderer and texture.  What would be the SDL 2.0 way of doing the SDL_BlitSurface? Thank you.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#If_your_game_wants_to_blit_surfaces_to_the_screen

Answer (score 0):

As for what @genpfault linked to in the comments:

```
/* ... */
SDL_BlitSurface(src, &src_rect, dst, &dst_rect);
/* ... */
```

Is the same as (SDL2):

```
/* ... */
// Create texture as late as possible to save resources:
SDL_Texture *src_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer_dst, src);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer_dst, src_texture, &src_rect, &dst_rect);
// Destroy texture as soon as possible to save resources:
SDL_DestroyTexture(src_texture);
/* ... */
SDL_RenderPresent(render_dst);
```

Your blit will be hardware-accelerated.

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused on how I get a surface to start with? I have a Window and Renderer - but I thought the SDL_Surface is the old SDL 1.2 convention?  Take this very simple example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/master/sdl/ttf.c - notice how it creates **two textures** to output text ('hello' in one font, 'world' in another font). I need to be able to modify the composited (combined) results, what the renderer got (all textures together). How do I get what the 'current window' has as a Surface or Texture?

Comment: @LinuxMars you can set another texture as render target and draw to it instead of screen. Reading rendering result to surface would be slow.

Comment: @keltar et al., reference this simple example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/master/sdl/ttf.c that is exactly what my SDL1.2 code is doing. It is creating **a unique texture for each word of text**, { texture: "hello", texture: "world", texture: "quick", texture: "brown" }.  What would be the the SDL 2.0 'best practice' in terms of how to draw hundreds of these textures to the single SDL_Window + SDL_Renderer? Are you saying to create a SDL_Window size texture and use that as an intermediate?

Comment: @LinuxMars if you combine them only once (or rarely), then yes. If content is dynamic, changing with every frame, then extra texture wouldn't help here.